# Changing JavaScript for Code Editor Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, editor

I am trying to add a code editor to a webpage. I have found an almost perfect one called [Editarea](https://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/editarea/exemples/exemple_full.html), and I would like to use it. I need help changing something about it for the way I want to use it on the webpage. It seems like it uses advanced (at least for me) JavaScript to generate what renders on the page. My JavaScript is a little rusty, and I need help to get its display just like I want. What I want is not to display any toolbar areas on the top or bottom. I do not need the toolbar because the user will set up the toolbar area controls options. Can someone take a look at this and see if they edit it to render as I want. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, Phil, I have seen this before.

Comment: That editor seems to be badly outdated: "_It works on IE 6 -> 8, Firefox 1.5 -> 3.5, Safari 3.1 -> 4, Opera 9 -> 10.1 and Chrome 1 -> 3_"

Comment: OK. I still like thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. At the bottom of the only JS file it links to in the head there is what becomes rendered by JavaScript CSS. Because I am rusty I had forgotten about using a code unminifier to see JS code clearly. Once I could read the code it was easy to do what I wanted. If anybody needs help to see the code that I changed to turn off the display of the toolbar I will gladly share. Phil